# Should I ask for a Letter of Rec from a Newer or Older Colleague?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I want to apply for a program where I will be doing research in a particular area for roughly 6 months.  This is an area of research I'm very deeply interested in, but I don't have any experience yet.  The program asks for a letter of recommendation and I'm a little torn who to ask to write this letter for me.  I'm currently a visiting assistant professor at a college and I have a colleague in my department who knows about my interest, but he's honestly someone who isn't super familiar with my work.  He's offered to write a letter with the caveat that this would be a relatively weak (albeit positive) letter.  On the other hand, I'm considering asking my thesis adviser to write a letter for me.  My concern however is that this would like like I'm relying too much on my grad school experience to get me into this program (it's been almost 2 years since I finished my PhD).  Unfortunately neither one will be able to speak that much to my experience in the intended area of research (since I have none).  Are there merits to relying on a newer colleague at this juncture, or is it safer to rely on someone more familiar with my work?

Comment: I assume that your skills, if not your direct experience, will be useful in the new area.

Comment: @Buffy Yes, i definitely have the prerequisite skills to enter this field, it’s just new for me.

Comment: What have you been doing in the 2 years since grad school?

Comment: @user151413 adjuncted for a year, and just secured a full time position last August.  Fall semester was too teaching intensive for me to work in research.  On top of that, I went to a very small grad school with little funding and didn’t make any collaborators during my time there.  Trying to change that now.

Comment: Ok. But if you want the last two years to be accounted for when assessing your application, it makes sense to have a letter from someone who can assess that time (can be your PhD advisor, but only if he/she can in fact assess it).

Answer (score 1):

You want letters from the people who know your work best. At this point that is probably your thesis advisor, with whom you have actually done research, even though in a different area. Be sure to explain your new interest when you ask your advisor for that letter.

[Recommendation letter from CS faculty for math grad school (and vice versa)](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/152204/recommendation-letter-from-cs-faculty-for-math-grad-school-and-vice-versa/152206#152206)

Comment: Yes, always from those who know you best. Preferably those who have worked with you.

Comment: Not clear that someone who knew you best 2 years ago (even better than anyone knows you now) is the best person to write a letter. After all, what people did *recently* matters, not what they did X years ago.

Comment: @user151413 Depends on the work you've done with the person who knows you more recently. The OP says not much in this case.

Comment: @Ethan Indeed, just saying that it is not clear in this case.